# Beautiful Soup get nested span by class within another span

Tags: beautifulsoup

Within a very large HTML page i want to get a `span` by `class` which is unique. The **child** `span` of this one, can be queried also by `class` but which is **not unique**.

```
...
<span class="uniqueParent">
   <span class="notUniqueChildClassName">
      I am the child
   </span>
</span> 
...
```

Output should be "I am the child".

I have tried:

```
s = soup.select('span[class="uniqueParent"] > span[class="notUniqueChildClassName"]')
s.text
```

and

```
s = soup.find('span[class="uniqueParent"] > span[class="notUniqueChildClassName"]')
s.text
```

But both did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selector with dot (e.g `.uniqueParent`, instead of `class="uniqueParent"`):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """\
<span class="uniqueParent">
   <span class="notUniqueChildClassName">
      I am the child
   </span>
</span> """


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one(".uniqueParent .notUniqueChildClassName").text)
```

Prints:

```
      I am the child
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the first attempt to

```
soup.select_one('span[class="uniqueParent"] > span[class="notUniqueChildClassName"]').text.strip()
```

on your actual html.

The output should be what you're looking for.